# Duplicate Localized Resource Files

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization, localizable.strings

I have an app that is intended to be localized into 5 languages via Localizable.strings files. When I view the Project > Info: Localizations information, I see duplicates of some languages (English, French, German) and an unintended language (Japanese).

[image]

My Resources in XCode, also appear off. But if I look at the Resources directory in Finder, they appear as I would expect.

[image] [image]

I have tried:

- Delete one of the duplicate files, via the - button, both lines disappear and the resource is gone from my Resource tree in XCode and my Resources directory in Finder.
- Product > Clean Build Folder
- Viewing subversion file structure in Versions

I'd appreciate any suggestions and an explanation. I'm using XCode 6.1.1 on Mavericks. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was running in the same issue and it was fixed by manually editing the `project.pbxproj` file inside the `.xcodeproj` Xcode project file container.

Before:

```
...
knownRegions = (
    English,
    German,
    en,
    de,
    Base,
);
...
```

After:

```
...
knownRegions = (
    en,
    de,
    Base,
);
...
```

Comment: Thanks this helped! Quick follow-up; when you changed your `knowRegion` values (removing English etc.) did you also change your `developmentRegion` value to `en` or did you leave it as `English`?

Comment: In my case, I deleted `English` from the `knownRegions` list and replaced `developmentRegion` with `en`; this had the desired effect (only one entry for "English" under "Localization", etc.).  This made sense to me because (among other reason) the `.lproj` folders were created as `en.lproj` and not `English.lproj`.  This is with Xcode 8 under OS X 10.11.6.